# Disabling fixed menu when viewport is smaller than x pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that works perfectly when viewed on a desktop, it's getting fixed in the sidebar using a simple jQuery script, but when you use your phone or a device with a width-viewport smaller than 767px it covers up the site.

So I'm currently looking for a way to disable the jQuery if the viewport is smaller than 767px. 
But how would I do that?

The jQuery code that gets executed (and should be disabled if the viewport is smaller than 767px) are the following:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function fixDiv() {
        var $cache = $('#block-menu-block-1'); 
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 315) 
            $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '30px'}); 
        else
            $cache.css({'position': 'relative', 'top': 'auto'});
    }
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
    fixDiv();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the approach I think is that detects the window size

```
if($(window).width() < 767) { 
   //disable what you want here or i think just hide the sidebar
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I ended up using:

if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width:47.938em)').matches)

Thanks! :)